# How would I display the elements of an arraylist of size i, into a case switch system?

Tags: java, arraylist, switch-statement

I've been working on a program to store book objects into a library, but I've come to a standstill.

I need to print out all Book objects from my arraylist, BookList, of unknown size (due to the possibility of including functionality of adding new books into the system), into a case switch system so you can select each option and edit the details.

Would I need to find the ArrayList.length and use that to determine the amount of switch statement options?

My code is below

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library_Tester {


public static void main (String[] args){





    System.out.println(" ===========================================");
    System.out.println("|  ==  ==  ===== ==    ==       ====        |");
    System.out.println("|  ==  ==  ==    ==    ==     =      =      |");
    System.out.println("|  ======  ====  ==    ==    =        =     |"); 
    System.out.println("|  ==  ==  ==    ==    ==     =      =      |");
    System.out.println("|  ==  ==  ===== ===== =====    ====        |");
    System.out.println(" ===========================================");



        System.out.println(" =======================================");
        System.out.println("|        Library Systems Inc            |");
        System.out.println(" =======================================");
        System.out.println("| Options:                              |");
        System.out.println("|       1. Add a book                   |");
        System.out.println("|       2. Edit a book's details        |");
        System.out.println("|       3. Delete a book                |");
        System.out.println("|       4. Loan a book                  |");
        System.out.println("|       5. Return a book                |");
        System.out.println("|       6. Exit the Program             |");
        System.out.println("|       7. Display all books in library |");
        System.out.println("|                                       |");
        System.out.println("|  *Type a number to make a selection*  |");
        System.out.println(" =======================================");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Selection: ");

        Book a = new Book();

        a.setTitle("Random ");
        a.setAuthor("Craig Robertson");
        a.setBookID("1847398812");
        a.setonLoan(false);
        a.setNumberofLoans(3);

        Book b = new Book();

        b.setTitle("The Last Refuge");
        b.setAuthor("Craig Robertson");
        b.setBookID("1471127753");
        b.setonLoan(false);
        b.setNumberofLoans(2);

        Book c = new Book();

        c.setTitle("The Bird That Did Not Sing");
        c.setAuthor("Alex Gray");
        c.setBookID("0751548278");
        c.setonLoan(true);
        c.setNumberofLoans(7);

        ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        BookList.add(a);
        BookList.add(b);
        BookList.add(c);





    Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Choice1;

       Choice1 = SC.nextInt();

       SC.close();


        switch (Choice1) {

        case 1:

            Scanner JK = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("'Add a book' selected");
          System.out.println(" ");


          break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("'Edit a book's details' selected");
            System.out.println("Which Book would you like to edit?");
            System.out.println("");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("'Delete a book' selected");
            break;

        case 4:
              System.out.println("'Loan a book' selected");
              break;

        case 5:
              System.out.println("'Return a book' selected");
              break;

        case 6:
              System.out.println("Goodbye!");
              System.exit(0);

              break;

        case 7:
              System.out.println("Displaying Books");
              System.out.println("");
              Book.showBooks(BookList);
              System.out.println("");

              break;      

        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid selection. Try again");


        }
      }
      }
```

Additional coding can be edited into this question on request.

An extra question would be: How do I edit the states of Book objects in the Array after this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Considered looping through the list?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the other question you asked about printing out books?

Comment: What is the exact question here ??? I guess you need to read http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a method to print ArrayList, then calling it in another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192644/creating-a-method-to-print-arraylist-then-calling-it-in-another-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a foreach statement

```
for (Book book : bookList){
    System.out.println(book.getTitle());
}
```

The idea is that, for each method you call in your case statement, your program will iterate over the list of books, either to display them, or to allow the user to modify them

I think it's just the opposite you are trying to do, which as my understanding is to iterate over the list and display all the options per book. Do it the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not, switch cases only accept values that are known constants at compile-time. 
In general, compilers will build you a jump table for the switch cases if they find nice constants for each case in your switch statement.
Note that switch only works with integer primitive types and enums, so you do need to use if/else statements if you're using other object types.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a switch case?

Get the user input, for example a bookId and search the list for that object, Then edit that objects details.

Steps;
1. Choose edit book
2. Ask for book ID
3. Get book with id from array list

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

// Populate list

private Book getBookById(int id) {
    Iterator<Book> obj = books.iterator();
    while(obj.hasNext()) {
        Book book = obj.next();
        if(book.id == id)
            return book;
    }
    return null;
}
```